# How to update jsonb sub element postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb

Table name: the_table
Column name: the_column

I want to update from this:
old_json: `{"aa": {"bb": {"asd": "asd", "qqq": "aqaq", "the_key": "the_value"}"}}`
modified json: `{"aa": {"bb": {"asd": "asd", "qqq": "aqaq", "the_key": "the_NEW_value"}"}}`

In my case I have to update many similar rows like above.
if I do like that `update the_table set the_column = jsonb_set(the_column, '{aa}', '"the_value"')` then result be like : `{"aa": "the_value"}`

Then I tried `update the_table set the_column = jsonb_set(the_column, '{aa: {bb: {the_key}}}', '"the_value"')` but it's does't work

So how to update jsonb correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=528c7cbb5a4331ef572e4c01b9ce41ab)

The second parameter of `jsonb_set()` is an text array which contains the keys as path to your values:

```
UPDATE the_table 
SET the_column = jsonb_set(the_column, '{aa, bb, the_key}', '"the_NEW_value"');
```